# Android code to get screenshot from background service

Tags: android, screenshot, background-service, rootview

I want to create a background app which will take screenshots of the actively running apps at some fixed time interval. I have tried the following code which works fine if we call from activity.

```
private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

This code works fine from activity. but i want to call the same code from background service.

Thanks. .. ...

Comment: by the above you can capture your activity screen itself, even if you write above code in background service

Comment: You can't capture the screen on no-rooted devices.